# Intel Virtualization Technologyを「有効」に出来ない

Tags: linux, virtualbox, bios

VirtualBox を使ってCentOSやUbuntuを学習しようとしています。

学習の前段としてIntel Virtualization Technologyを「有効」にするように記述されています。

[image: text 指示 virtual box]

私の端末はNECの「LAVIE VEGA LV750/RAL PC-LV750RAL」です。
端末の起動時に「F2」を押しBIOS設定画面のAdvanceタグを見ると
"Virtualization Technology”を有効化する項目が出来ません。

[image: BIOS]

念のためVirtual Checkerを起動させてみると、サポートされていないようです。

[image: Virtual Checker]

以前、この項目の事は知らず仮想環境でLinux OSを試した事があるのですが、挙動がおかしかったのはこのせいなのでしょうか？

このような場合、この端末ではあきらめるしかないのでしょうか？　何か方法をご存じの方いらっしゃいましたら教えてください。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LAVIE LV750](https://www.nec-lavie.jp/navigate/products/pc/201q/01/lavie/lv/spec/) 仕様書によると CPU は [i7-9750H](https://www.intel.co.jp/content/www/jp/ja/products/sku/191045/intel-core-i79750h-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-50-ghz/specifications.html) であり CPU 仕様としては `vt-x` には対応済みなわけですが、ビジネス向けモデルは `vt-x` や `vt-d` を BIOS/UEFI setup 画面から有効化したり無効化したりできないものがあります。たぶん当該 LAVIE LV750 もそういう仕様なのだと思われます。

メーカー（この場合は NEC ですが）としては PC アセンブリ（完成品）として `vt-x` 等の動作を保証していないということと思われます。

あとはあなたがどう考えるか次第なわけですが

- 別マシンに乗り換えてもよいし（その分の費用は当然発生）
- 当該マシンの `vt-x` を無理やり有効化してもよいし（改造相当に扱われメーカー保証がなくなるかも）

お好きなほうで。後者なら検索すれば例えば
[LL750 で Intel VT を有効化](https://pontapapa.hatenablog.com/entry/20110417/1303029391)
[LL750/T の Intel VT-x を有効化](https://assimane.blog.ss-blog.jp/2012-02-08)
みたいなものは見つかります（がオイラはこのマシン持っていませんしリンク先内容が正しいかどうかなどは一切保証しません）

Comment: 少し敷居が高いようです。別の端末を使ってみます